# Dictionary requires a model item of type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.List'1[ProjectName.ViewModels.ProductViewModel]'?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple table - Selectively queried using a SqlCommand statement and then read into the HTML table using a SqlDataReader. I want to be able to update the table contents by making use of a simple HTML form (acquiring its functionality from a controller - namely: UpdateProductPage and UpdateProduct). I am making use of a wrapper view model in order to associate a product with its specific type. However, i cannot seem to get to the point where i am even able to open the view containing the HTML form used to update the contents as i am stopped by the following error:

" The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Homework_5.ViewModels.WrapperViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Homework_5.ViewModels.ProductViewModel]' "

I am struggling to make any sense of the error.

Here is my wrapper view model:

```
namespace Homework_5.ViewModels
{
    public class WrapperViewModel
    {
        public ProductViewModel product;
        public List<TypeViewModel> typeList = new List<TypeViewModel>();
    }
}
```

UpdateProductPage Controller - Which does work (tested using breakpoints) - Catch is never met:

```
//Update an existing product in the database
        public ActionResult UpdateProductPage(int id)
        {
            WrapperViewModel updateModel = new WrapperViewModel();
            updateModel.product = Global.productList.Where(p => p.ProductID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand webstoreCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from ProductType", webstoreConnection);
                webstoreConnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader webstoreReader = webstoreCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (webstoreReader.Read())
                {
                    TypeViewModel type = new TypeViewModel();
                    type.TypeID = (int)webstoreReader["ID"];
                    type.TypeName = webstoreReader["TypeName"].ToString();
                    updateModel.typeList.Add(type);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ViewBag.Status = 0;
            }
            finally
            {
                webstoreConnection.Close();
            }
            return View(updateModel);
        }
```

UpdateProduct Controller - Is never run (according to breakpoints - exception thrown before reaching this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateProduct(int Id, string Description, double Price, int Quantity, string Image, int TypeID)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand webstoreUpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("Update Product Set Description = '" + Description + "', Price = '" + Price + "', Quantity = '" + Quantity + " where ID = " + Id, webstoreConnection);
                webstoreConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ViewBag.Status = 0;
            }
            finally
            {
                webstoreConnection.Close();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("ViewProductPage");
        }
```

HTML form (with the necessary inputs - which are supposed to be pre-filled with the respective information:

```
model Homework_5.ViewModels.WrapperViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UpdateProductPage";
}

<h2>Update Selected Product - ID Value: @Model.product.ProductID</h2>

<div class="update-product-contents">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateProduct", "AdminProduct", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Id", Model.product.ProductID, new { @class = "form-control" });
        <label>Description:</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Description", Model.product.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", required = "required" });
        <label>Price:</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Price", Model.product.Price, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", required = "required" });
        <label>Quantity:</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Quantity", Model.product.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", required = "required" });
        <label>Image:</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Image", Model.product.ImagePath, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file", required = "required" });
        <label>Product Type:</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("TypeID", new SelectList(Model.typeList, "TypeID", "TypeName", Model.product.Type.TypeID), new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" });
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Add to product database</button>
    }
</div>
```

And lastly the button which is suppose to open the update page:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("UpdateProductPage", "AdminProduct", new { id = product.ProductID })">
       <i class="fas fa-edit" id="edit-icon"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: you didn't include you html form, you pasted your controller twice in your question

Comment: Aplogies. It is updated now - Thanks for the notice

Comment: What is the name of the cshtml View file that contains the form?

Comment: @SohaibAfzal It is called: "UpdateProductPage.cshtml"